# Update price on change inlcuding on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, calc

This is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/btekbtek/6gxztk4f/6/

When I type qty, I automatically calculate price.
I want also include select option that is adding
£1 per 1 qty.

If someone type 10 qty - price should be qty10*(£1*10)*price

Currently when I add:

```
 // update price if option change
 var optionprice = 0;
 var getPriceOption = function() {
   jQuery("#select_21").change(function() {
     if (jQuery(this).val() === '63') {
       optionprice = 0;
     } else {
       optionprice = 1;
     }
   }); //end update optionprice
   return optionprice;
 }; //end get PriceOption

 console.log(getPriceOption);
```

getPriceOption is undefined. I was trying to add it after before and same result.

I cannot change anything in HTML, just in jQuery.

Comment: Did you leave the `()` off of the `getPriceOption`?  Because that should log as a function, not undefined.  And if you did, the result is undefined because `optionprice` will not be defined until the change happens.

Comment: So basically you want to perform operation automatic price calculation based on the dropdown change?

Comment: I updated jsfidlle because wasnt working. When we type qty its updating number. @Taplar should be there optionprice, but its not working anyway. Jishan - Its now automaticlly update on type number but should include dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was enough:

```
var updateprice = $("#select_21 option:selected").attr('price');
```

added in :

```
while (i--) {
         if (qty >= tierPrices[i]['price_qty']) {
           var updateprice = $("#select_21 option:selected").attr('price');
           var calc_price = tierPrices[i]['price'] * qty + (updateprice*qty);
           return (calc_price).toFixed(2)
         }
       }
```